# How to generate a default record in an entity (Core Data)?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I'm just doing my first steps in Core Data and would like to change a piece of my code which uses a simple plist to store some preference data of a program. I would like to use Core Data instead. Just for educational reason.

So basically I created an entity named "setup" with a bunch of attributes like "language", "debug info", "server ip" and so on. There should be only one data record in the entity as there is no sense to keep multiple setups.

I then created the GUI in the interface builder by alt-dragging the entity over the GUI window. I choosed "single item view". I can run the code but there is a problem:

I'm not able to change the content of the contols. I assume it's simply because there is no record in the entity. So my question is, how to create a "default" entry? I don't want to use the "Master/Detail view" as I simply need just one data record which should be generated automatically in case the storedata-file isn't created yet.

Comment: "Core Logic"? Do you mean "Core Data"?

Comment: yes, sorry for the confusion :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem so far. I added the following lines to the method "- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext". It creates a default record in the entity on the first call of the method. The values of the attributes are set up in the data model.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Setup" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
[request setIncludesSubentities:NO]; //Omit subentities. Default is YES (i.e. include subentities)
NSError *err;
NSUInteger count = [managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:request error:&err];
if(count==NSNotFound || count==0) 
{
    [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Setup" inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext];
}

[request release];
```

I'm not sure if it's the correct way to handle it, especially I doubt  that's the right place. I'm missing the method which is called after the Core Data has been set up. Any suggestions are highly welcome!